# Limit of non-increasing sets of polyehdron is polyhedron

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis

Suppose that we have a sequence of polyhedron $C^k$ that is non-increasing, i.e., we have $C^{k+1}\subseteq C^k$.  Suppose moreover that
each $C^k$ is formed by the convex hull of at most $n$ points, where $n$ is a fixed constant independent of $k$, i.e., $C^k=\mbox{conv}(z_1^k,\ldots,z_n^k)$, where $\mbox{conv}$ means the convex hull.  Define the set limit $$C^\infty=\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty} C^k$$
It is clear that $C^\infty$ is compact and convex.

Is $C^\infty$ necessarily a polyhedron? That is, is it necessarily the case that there exist points $v_1,\dots,v_m$ such that $C^\infty=\mbox{conv}\lbrace v_1,\ldots, v_m\rbrace$?

Comment: It is a reasonable (albeit not well-written) question. But in the present form it does not meet the MSE quality standards. Please describe your thoughts about the question, what did you try to solve it...